# Datatable with static json data source

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I am trying to create a datatable with static data in json format without getting the json source data by hitting the server through ajax request.
Tried hard to find a way to do it, but no luck.Is it possible to do it with static json data variable as shown below,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery DataTable</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo_table_jui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="complete.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


  <script>
  $(function() {
  var jsonData = [{"userID":"1","userName":"name1"},{"userID":"2","userName":"name2"},{"userID":"3","userName":"name3"}];
 $('#example').dataTable({
  data: jsonData,
      columns: [
          { data: 'userID' },
          { data: 'userName' }
      ]
 });

  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" align="center">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>UserID</th>
   <th>userName</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please give example ways of doing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try to remove $function() and replace with `$(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: Your code is actually [working](https://jsfiddle.net/gp8mter6/1/)

Comment: tried $(document).ready() also. No use @john

Comment: can you please make it to work for me also? @Yuri

Comment: @Anonymous check the link in my answer. And as John suggested, put your code in $(document).ready...

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{"userID":"1","userName":"name1"},{"userID":"2","userName":"name2"},{"userID":"3","userName":"name3"}];
 $('#example').dataTable({
  data: data,
  columns: [
   { data: 'userID' },
   { data: 'userName' }
  ]
 });

  });

Comment: tried not working @Yuri

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By including your JS code in `$(function(){})`, it will be run before your `<table>` is created. So you have to: 1. put that code right at the end of your `<body>`; 2. put in `$(document).ready();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jsonData = [{"userID":"1","userName":"name1"},{"userID":"2","userName":"name2"},{"userID":"3","userName":"name3"}];
    $('#example').dataTable({
        data: jsonData,
        columns: [
            { data: 'userID' },
            { data: 'userName' }
        ]
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp8mter6/1/)

Comment: with exact same code inside document ready is not working. any idea?

Comment: is this related to the versions of jquery or datatable which am using?

Comment: Do you have any error in your console? Also try a newer jQuery version

Comment: Solved the problem by replacing jquery and datatable with newer version. Thanks